# url recognition affiliate code insertion and abbreviation

Tags: php, sql, url

There's a form in my project. I want to shorten this form by adding my reference code to the link I received.

recognize the url from the form, add different affiliate codes, and then shorten it.

writes to the database by adding code to the url in the following code snippet. but I couldn't put the else structure in place for different url likes.

I'd be glad if you could help.

The sample results should be as follows;

****Original Link    --- --- ---- ---- ---- ----        Result ****

[www.Mediamarkt.de](http://www.Mediamarkt.de)   => [www.Mediamarkt.de/aff=12115](http://www.Mediamarkt.de/aff=12115)?

[www.otto.de](http://www.otto.de)         => [www.otto.de/aff=6115](http://www.otto.de/aff=6115)?

[www.amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de)       => [www.amazon.de/aff=2519](http://www.amazon.de/aff=2519)?

[www.nike.com](http://www.nike.com)      =>  [www.nike.com/aff=ad587s](http://www.nike.com/aff=ad587s)?

do not add affiliate tag to other different links

.. Etc

```html
<?php
require_once('config.php');

//PDO Connection | 数据库连接
try{
    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8mb4',DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if(DEBUG_MODE)die($e->getMessage());
    die('Fail to Connect the Database.');
}

// Insert URL to database 
function urlInsert($params){
    $url=$params['url'].'';
    $curl=urlencode($url);
    $host=parse_url($url)['host'];
    if(empty($host)){
        $host=parse_url('http://'.$url)['host'];
        $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=12115?';
    }

if ($url="www.Mediamarkt.de"){
    $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=12115?';
 else 

   if ($url="www.otto.de"){
    $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=615?';
 else 

   if ($url="www.amazon.de"){
    $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=2519?';
 else

   if ($url="www.nike.com"){
    $url='https://'.$curl.'ad587s?';
 else

    $ip=trim(end(explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])));
    
    do{
        $ukey=ukeyGen();
    }while(ukeyCheck($ukey));
    
    global $dbc;
    try{
        $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `".DB_TABLE."` (`domain`, `url`, `ukey`, `ip`) VALUES 
                            (:host, :url, :ukey, :ip)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':host',$host);
        $stmt->bindParam(':url',$url);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ukey',$ukey);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ip',$ip);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()){
            return $ukey;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if(DEBUG_MODE)die($e->getMessage());
        die('Fail to excute command');
    }
}
```

Comment: what does java have to do with that?

Comment: _“but I couldn't put the else structure in place for different url likes”_ - what are you referring to here? `else` - to what `if`? And did you even make any attempt? I don’t see even `aff=` _anywhere_ in the code you have shown, so I am assuming, you didn’t?

Comment: I'm new to this site. I'm trying to make a correction, but I don't know where it's made.

Add aff code is here ;

        $url='https://tr.rdrtr.com/aff_c?offer_id=3107&aff_id=25309&url=https://'.$curl.'%3Futm_source%3Daff_t%26utm_medium%3Dcps%26utm_campaign%3Dgelirortaklari%26utm_subaff%3D%7Baff_id%7D%26adjust_tracker%3D21ouxa_bfy1cc%26adjust_campaign%3Dperformics_tr%26adjust_adgroup%3D1%26adjust_label%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D';

In the name of the lack of confusion I wrote shortening this part in the question

Comment: Here's the code structure I'm thinking of. 

if ($url="www.Mediamarkt.de"){
            $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=12115?';
         else 
       if ($url="www.otto.de"){
            $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=615?';
         else 

       if ($url="www.amazon.de"){
            $url='https://'.$curl.'aff=2519?';
         else

       if ($url="www.nike.com"){
            $url='https://'.$curl.'ad587s?';
         else

Comment: Use an array to store your aff codes under the host name - `$affCodes = ['www.Mediamarkt.de' => '12115', 'www.otto.de' => '6115', …];` Then you can use `isset` to check if a code for the host name you extracted from the URL exists in that array, and if so, take it directly from there. That saves you from creating long if-else-elseif-… blocks.

Comment: thank you for answer. but i can't do it with array. ( i don't know use array.). but i want learn to array. can you edit the following solution with array.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by editing the code as below.

I don't know if this solution would be more practical with array. If there are any friends who can edit with array, I want to learn.

```
    <?php
    require_once('config.php');

    //PDO Connection | 数据库连接
    try{
        $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8mb4',DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if(DEBUG_MODE)die($e->getMessage());
        die('Fail to Connect the Database.');
    }

    // Insert URL to database 
    function urlInsert($params){
        $url=$params['url'].'';
        $curl=urlencode($url);
        $host=parse_url($url)['host'];
       if ($url=="www.Mediamarkt.de"){
        $surl='https://'.$curl.'/aff=12115?';
}elseif ($url=="www.otto.de"){
        $surl='https://'.$curl.'/aff=615?';
}elseif ($url=="www.amazon.de"){
        $surl='https://'.$curl.'/aff=2519?';
}elseif ($url=="www.nike.com"){
        $surl='https://'.$curl.'/ad587s?';
 }else

        $ip=trim(end(explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])));
        
        do{
            $ukey=ukeyGen();
        }while(ukeyCheck($ukey));
        
        global $dbc;
        try{
            $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `".DB_TABLE."` (`domain`, `url`, `ukey`, `ip`) VALUES 
                                (:host, :url, :ukey, :ip)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':host',$host);
            $stmt->bindParam(':url',$url);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ukey',$ukey);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ip',$ip);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount()){
                return $ukey;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if(DEBUG_MODE)die($e->getMessage());
            die('Fail to excute command');
        }
    }
```